# Google Apps Script Calendar Service: Process many events in chunks: How to programmatically trigger next function run to continue with next chunk?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60834955/google-apps-script-calendar-service-how-to-avoid-exceeding-maximum-execution-ti).

```
function renameEvents() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Calendar Id");
  var startTime = new Date(1850, 0, 1);
  var endTime = new Date(2100, 0, 1);
  var events = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  if (!(sp.getProperty("count")) || sp.getProperty("count") == 0) {
    var count = 0;
  else if ((sp.getProperty("count") > 0) {
    var count = sp.getProperty("count");
  }

  for (var i = count; i < events.length; i++) {
    events[i].setTitle(events[i].getTitle() + " something");
    events[i].setDescription(events[i].getDescription() + " something else");
    sp.setProperty("count", i)
  }
}
```

The initial function run is time-triggered. How to programmatically trigger the next function run to continue with the next chunk?

Comment: Please put everything you require in your question in your question don't depend upon links. We may just not want to bother following that link to figure out what your question is. Like me.

Comment: Isn't the question clearly formulated here? Anyway, I've edited my post.

Comment: According to the documentation: `getEvents(startTime, endTime) CalendarEvent[] Gets all events that occur within a given time range.` so there are no more events.

Comment: As the script runtime is limited to 6 mins I cannot process all events at once. That's why I need to process them in chunks. The function should trigger the script execution as long as there are still events left to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of the following script. This script is from [the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60834955/7108653) in your question.

  ```
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Calendar Id");
  var startTime = new Date(1850, 0, 1);
  var endTime = new Date(2100, 0, 1);
  var events = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    events[i].setTitle(events[i].getTitle() + " something");
    events[i].setDescription(events[i].getDescription() + " something else");
  }
  ```
- You want to modify the event title and event description of all events in the Google calendar.

### Issue and workaround:

- In your current script, the title and event description of all events try to modify in the for loop. And in your current script, the loop is run until an error occurs. And when the error occurs, the loop is started from `count`using using the time-driven trigger. I understood like this.
- In your above script, when the number of events are large, the maximum execution time is over. Because I think that the cost of `setTitle` and `setDescription` is high.
- In your current script, in addition to `setTitle` and `setDescription`, `setProperty` is used in the for loop. In this case, the process cost will be more high.

In my answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose to use [the batch request](https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch) for your situation. The Calendar API can be run by the batch request. The batch request is run with the asynchronous process, and can run 100 requests by one API call. By this, the process cost can be reduced. So I thought that when the batch request is used for your situation, your all tasks might be able to be achieve by one running script.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

In order to use this sample script, please install a Google Apps Script library of [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest). You can see the method for installing the library at https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install.

#### 2. Run sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script. And [please enable Google Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). And please set your calendar ID to `calendarId`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const calendarId = "###";

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var startTime = new Date(1850, 0, 1);
  var endTime = new Date(2100, 0, 1);
  var events = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);

  // Create requests for the batch request.
  const reqs = events.map(e => ({
    method: "PUT",
    endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events/${e.getId().replace("@google.com", "")}`,
    requestBody: {
      start: {dateTime: e.getStartTime().toISOString()},
      end: {dateTime: e.getEndTime().toISOString()},
      summary: e.getTitle() + " something",
      description: e.getDescription() + " something else"
    }
  }));

  // Run batch requests.
  const limit = 100;
  const split = Math.ceil(reqs.length / limit);
  for (let i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    BatchRequest.Do({batchPath: "batch/calendar/v3", requests: reqs.splice(0, limit)});
  }
}
```

- When you run the function of `myFunction`, the title and description of all events are modified by the method of Events: update in Calendar API.

### Note:

- **This script modifies the title and description of all events. So please be careful this. So at first, as a test run, I would like to test for the small number of events.**
- In my environment, when I tested above script for 100 events, the process time was about 7 seconds. I'm not sure about the number of your total events.
- In this answer, I proposed to use the method of Events: update instead of the method of Events: patch. Because when Events: patch is used, I confirmed that only a part of requested all events were modified. I think that this might be a bug. So I used the method of "Events: update". In this case, I could confirm that all events were modified.
- Please use this script with V8.

### References:

- [Sending Batch Requests](https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch)
- [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update)
- [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

### Added:

In this sample script, no GAS library is used.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const calendarId = "###";

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var startTime = new Date(1850, 0, 1);
  var endTime = new Date(2100, 0, 1);
  var events = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);

  // Create requests for the batch request.
  const reqs = events.map(e => ({
    method: "PUT",
    endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events/${e.getId().replace("@google.com", "")}`,
    requestBody: {
      start: {dateTime: e.getStartTime().toISOString()},
      end: {dateTime: e.getEndTime().toISOString()},
      summary: e.getTitle() + " something",
      description: e.getDescription() + " something else"
    }
  }));

  // Run batch requests.
  const limit = 100;
  const split = Math.ceil(reqs.length / limit);
  const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
  for (let i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    const object = {batchPath: "batch/calendar/v3", requests: reqs.splice(0, limit)};
    const payload = object.requests.reduce((s, e, i) => s += "Content-Type: application/http\r\nContent-ID: " + i + "\r\n\r\n" + e.method + " " + e.endpoint + "\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n" + JSON.stringify(e.requestBody) + "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n", "--" + boundary + "\r\n");
    const params = {method: "post", contentType: "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary, payload: payload, headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}, muteHttpExceptions: true};
    UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/" + object.batchPath, params);
  }
}
```

### Added:

- You want to achieve above without using Calendar API.

For this, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, there is the syntax error for the following part.

  ```
  if (!(sp.getProperty("count")) || sp.getProperty("count") == 0) {
    var count = 0;
  else if ((sp.getProperty("count") > 0) {
    var count = sp.getProperty("count");
  }
  ```

  - Please modify `else if ((sp.getProperty("count") > 0) {` to `} else if (sp.getProperty("count") > 0) {`.
- The value retrieved by `getProperty` is the string type. From `nothing happes` in [your replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61895200/google-apps-script-calendar-service-process-many-events-in-chunks-how-to-progr/61905864?noredirect=1#comment110344318_61905864), I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

So how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
if (!(sp.getProperty("count")) || sp.getProperty("count") == 0) {
  var count = 0;
else if ((sp.getProperty("count") > 0) {
  var count = sp.getProperty("count");
}
```

To:

```
var count = Number(sp.getProperty("count")) || 0;
```

#### Reference:

- [getProperty(key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getProperty(String))

Comment: Thank you very much! While this is definitely an interesting approach it doesn't actually answer my question how to programmatically (instead of timely) trigger a function run. I would prefer a solution without third party libraries.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I added one more sample script without using the GAS library. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you also add an answer to my question how to programmatically (instead of timely) trigger a function run (without Google Calendar API)?

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the result you tested of my workaround? Because from your replying, I couldn't understand about it. When an error occurs, I have to modify it.

Comment: @Ben By the way, it seems that your script is the same with [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60835604/7108653). When I saw it, the answerer says `each time you run it it'll continue along the calendar events from where the last one stopped.`. From this, can I ask you about the current issue of your script? My answer is for directly achieving your goal by reducing the process cost. But when I think about your question, I would like to correctly understand about your current issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! To be honest, I didn't test your workaround yet as I am actually looking for a solution without Google Calendar API.

Comment: As for my current issue, please see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229940/google-apps-script-calendar-service-how-to-store-and-retrieve-calendarevents-us/61324179#comment108424426_61229940), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229940/google-apps-script-calendar-service-how-to-store-and-retrieve-calendarevents-us/61324179#comment108424757_61229940) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229940/google-apps-script-calendar-service-how-to-store-and-retrieve-calendarevents-us/61324179#comment109239957_61324179). Have a nice Weekend!

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I could understand that you didn't test my workaround. About your replying, can you give me a time to understand about your current situation? About `How to programmatically trigger the next function run to continue with the next chunk?`, can I ask you about your current issue? I would like to think of your issue after I could correctly understand about your current situation. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind words as well as for your understanding! Well, I actually just don't know how to trigger a function call within a script. Let's pretend I process the events in chunks of 100 to avoid timeout. So after processing 100 events, the function aborts. If there are more events left, the function should be triggered again. If there are no more events left, nothing happes until the function will be triggered again by a time trigger.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I added the modification point for your script without using Calendar API. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you very much! But that actually still doesn't answer my question of how to programmatically trigger a function run. Anyway, thank you very much! (Maybe I should ask another question describing my goal a better way.)

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I could understand about your replying. I would like to confirm your new post. When you posted it, I would like to check it.